# Expo - Lock orientation to landscape

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to have my expo react-native app displayed in landscape

I edited app.json to have:

```
"orientation": "landscape",
```

And this in App.js

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  // ...
  componentDidMount() {
    ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE);
  }
  // ...
}
```

I try to run in android emulator, but it looks like the emulator is locked on portrait mode.
The physical orientation of the device is landscape, The app is "streched" to fit a landscape screen, but android seems lock in portrait mode:

https://i.ibb.co/dK54ngp/Capture.png

I check the device setting and "Auto-rotate" is ON.

I think I am missing something but I can't find what.

Can someone tell me what needs to be done to lock the app to landscape mode ?

*Edit*:

It seems to work with the Nexus 5 emulator, not on Nexus 9

Comment: Check this: https://forums.expo.io/t/screen-orientation-not-locking-on-landscape/19949

Comment: Thank for the help ! In my situation I'm calling lockAsync on App mount (top-most component). I don't see how I could call that earlier like he said he did

Comment: App.json change is enough for this. However it does not automatically reflect this during debugging (making us think it doesnt work and do ScreenOrientation). Do the change, close debug sessions and try again.

Answer (score 10):

for me just changing orientation in app.json is enough, the code is not needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26885997)

Comment: He is asking how to display his app in landscape mode and I just answered it.

Comment: You can read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). A link and simple explanation describing why only `changing orientation in app.json is enough`, would improve your answer. The OP already has `"orientation": "landscape"` so I don't think your answer in its current state is adding anything beneficial.

Comment: I told him to remove the code part. Also since it worked for me I don't know what's wrong with my answer

Answer (score 4):

change with this.

```
  import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';
ScreenOrientation.unlockAsync()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some bugs related to orientation, in the last Expo version.

Check this out: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8210

Answer (score 1):

`App/tsx`/`App.jsx`

```js
import * as ScreenOrientation from "expo-screen-orientation";
ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE);
// or
ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(5);
```

Reference: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/